# MySQL ORDER BY FIELD equivalent in Redis search

Tags: mysql, search, redis

How do I accomplish this custom sort by field feature available in MySQL in Redis search?

select * from product ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1,4)

For some business reason, I need to enforce custom orders.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your redis data structure? what redis data types are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not equivalent of the FIELD function in RediSearch.

With FT.SEARCH / [SORTBY](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Sorting/#specifying_sortby) you can sort results using a field.
In your hash, you may create a new field (NUMERIC SORTABLE) holding a value that will be used to sort the result. Of course, that would work only if you don't want need to specify a different order on each query.

Second option: This could be handled by using FT.AGGREGATE with an appropriate function. You may have a look at the [existing function](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Aggregations/#list_of_field_apply_functions) and see if one could be used for that. IF the function does not exist, you may do a [feature request](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues).

A third option is to implement your own scoring function using the [extension API](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Extensions/#extending_redisearch) (but it may be over engineering ...)